# groovy: how to compare keys of two maps, and combine values for output

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, key-value

I am attempting to match the keys of two separate maps (one of which has a nested list of values) and if the keys are identical, then take the values of each map and print them out.

```
    Map 1 = [1210910348504950525757554952 : 40_b4_f0_a4_9d_80]

    Map 2 = [1210910348504950525757554952:[1, 23230967]
```

As a result, I need to get an output that looks something like this:

```
    Map1Value.Map2(NestedValue1).Map2(NestedValue2)

    40_b4_f0_a4_9d_80.1.23230967
```

I can't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm hoping you just have a simplistic example, and there are really more than just the one key in each of the maps.

If that's the case, maybe something like:

```
Map map1 = [ 444: 'aaa', 555: 'bbb', 666: 'zzz' ]
Map map2 = [ 444: [ 'cc', 'dd', 'ff' ], 666: ['111', '222'] ]

map1.keySet().each { key ->
    List v2 = map2[key]
    if ( v2 ) {
       println (([map1[key]] + v2).join("."))
    }
}
```

or something a little shorter even:

```
map1.keySet().intersect( map2.keySet() ).each { key ->
   println (([map1[key]] + map2[key]).join("."))
}
```

both of them output:

```
aaa.cc.dd.ff
zzz.111.222
```

Note that the 555 key did not match in the 2nd map, so it didn't output.
Note I'm creating a list out of just the value from map1, then adding the list of values from map2 to it, then joining them with periods.